# GTK+ buffer in g_input_stream_read

Tags: c, gtk

I load data with function:

```
gssize          g_input_stream_read    (GInputStream *stream,
                                        void *buffer, gsize count,
                                        GCancellable *cancellable,
                                        GError **error);
```

What is ma value of buffer parameter. How can I know what should be equal to buffer?

I make:

```
#define LOAD_BUFFER_SIZE 65536
```

But when i try to load image, only visible part of the image.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `buffer` is a pointer to the memory you have allocated to contain what `g_input_stream_read` reads.  It must be big enough to contain `count` bytes.

Could you expand this question, by showing with code samples how you are allocating the memory for `buffer` and how you called `g_input_stream_read` exactly?

Here is [documentation on using g_input_stream_read](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/stable/GInputStream.html#g-input-stream-read).